# Using Meteor with npm node-mangafox

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, meteor, npm

I have been playing around for a while with Meteor, I am Jumping the Gun trying to Use a npm Package without fulling understanding how to use Js but the way i learn is by doing.

Would someone be so kind as to explain how i would go about Using npm **node-mangafox** it uses an api to get information from the Site but i have no clue how i would go about displaying this in a Html file or even how to get the data i am looking for do i use Json or JavaScript.

I am totally new to Programming please be kind.

So i am Using a Normal Meteor build and then Installed "npm node-mangafox" this installed correctly i then successfully imported it into my project (Server) but now i have no clue as to call/display the data.

My attempt at this.

```
<template name="manga">
    <div id="manga"></div>

      <script>

      var mangaFox = { function (getManga) {
      document.getElementById("manga").innerHTML = (list);
      }};

      </script>
</template>
```

This is my attempt this is probably very wrong - but i am just trying to get data to display to start understanding how the API caller works via this package.

**Note** i am a beginner at (HTML/CSS/JS/JSON) but this is helping me to learn :) !

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

Move your javascript code into a template helper,

You can import the library like this

```
import mangaFox from 'node-magafox'
```

Make a call to get the data and save to a local variable

```
//Gets all available manga titles
mangaFox.getManga( mangaData => {

})
```

Remove the `<script>` block from your template

Put in a `{{#each}}` block to display each of the mangas

Don't use `.innerHTML`, it can be done, but you have a templating system to do that for you

Plenty more learning there for you...

Comment: Hi, Mikkel,  I attempted this but failed could i get a little bit more information please? Also thank you!

Comment: The problem is I don't know what to I need to tell you. If you are new to programming, you probably haven't used Meteor before. If you share your project with me I could add some code to get you started if you like

Comment: Hello, Mikkel, I am a bit shy when it comes to shearing my work :D But i have it Up Via Github please feel free to take a look i am simply trying to output the information from the Api where the Carosuel place holder is located on the Home  page. 

[link](https://github.com/nexthazard/New_SPA_Meteor)

Comment: The link doesn't work - is it a private repo? Don't worry, I'm not in the business of stealing people's code. It's hard enough debugging your own code, let alone trying to maintain someone else's. You might need to share the repo with me